# Google Map Place Picker package doesn't show the picked result

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I am using [google_maps_place_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_place_picker) package and I am having two issues:

1. When I search for a location, I only see the text "Searching".
2. When I drag my pin to a location, I see what appears to be a white background box but do not see the description of the location I am choosing.

Please see the screenshot.

[image]

Here's the code which I am using:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_place_picker/google_maps_place_picker.dart';

class GoogleMapsPlacePicker extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/google-search-map';
  // Light Theme
  final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    // Background color of the FloatingCard
    cardColor: Colors.white,
    buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
      // Select here's button color
      buttonColor: Colors.black,
      textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
    ),
  );

  // Dark Theme
  final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    // Background color of the FloatingCard
    cardColor: Colors.grey,
    buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
      // Select here's button color
      buttonColor: Colors.yellow,
      textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
    ),
  );

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Map Place Picker Demo',
      theme: lightTheme,
      darkTheme: darkTheme,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      home: HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  static final kInitialPosition = LatLng(-33.8567844, 151.213108);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  PickResult selectedPlace;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Google Map Place Picer Demo"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Load Google Map"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return PlacePicker(
                          apiKey: 'my_api_key',
                          initialPosition: HomePage.kInitialPosition,
                          useCurrentLocation: true,
                          selectInitialPosition: true,

                          //usePlaceDetailSearch: true,
                          onPlacePicked: (result) {
                            selectedPlace = result;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          forceSearchOnZoomChanged: true,
                          automaticallyImplyAppBarLeading: false,
                          autocompleteLanguage: "en",
                          region: 'tz',
                          //selectInitialPosition: true,
                          selectedPlaceWidgetBuilder: (_, selectedPlace, state, isSearchBarFocused) {
                            print("state: $state, isSearchBarFocused: $isSearchBarFocused");
                            return isSearchBarFocused
                                ? Container()
                                : FloatingCard(
                                    bottomPosition: 0.0, // MediaQuery.of(context) will cause rebuild. See MediaQuery document for the information.
                                    leftPosition: 0.0,
                                    rightPosition: 0.0,
                                    width: 500,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                                    child: state == SearchingState.Searching
                                        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                                        : RaisedButton(
                                            child: Text("Pick Here"),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              // IMPORTANT: You MUST manage selectedPlace data yourself as using this build will not invoke onPlacePicker as
                                              //            this will override default 'Select here' Button.
                                              print("do something with [selectedPlace] data");
                                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                            },
                                          ),
                                  );
                          },
                          pinBuilder: (context, state) {
                            if (state == PinState.Idle) {
                              return Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined);
                            } else {
                              return Icon(Icons.location_on_rounded);
                            }
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              selectedPlace == null ? Container() : Text(selectedPlace.formattedAddress ?? ""),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: What error message are you seeing? Are you using a Google Maps project with Places API enabled and is linked to a valid billing account?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable billing account. After that you api key will work.

Answer (score -2):

you must provide the api key .Also the api key must be valid. This means your api key must be supported to get map results.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).